# matplotlib colorbar to show density of each bin

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have below data for which I am plotting a 2d histogram

```
data1 = [68, 64, 59, 65, 69, 64, 67, 67, 62, 64, 66, 64, 67, 
60, 64, 67, 67, 66, 62, 61, 63, 66, 67, 67, 68, 71, 60, 65, 66, 
64, 64, 65, 68, 69, 68, 61, 63, 67, 63, 61, 68, 66, 67, 63, 72, 
68, 63, 68]

data2 = [21.5, 18.0, 20.0, 21.0, 20.5, 18.5, 21.0, 19.5, 20.0, 
18.5, 20.5, 18.5, 18.0, 19.5, 21.0, 20.0, 20.0, 19.0, 17.0, 
17.5, 19.0, 18.5, 20.5, 19.5, 20.0, 20.0, 18.5, 20.0, 21.0, 
19.5, 20.0, 20.0]

data3 = data1[:32]
```

Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
hist, xbins, ybins, im = ax.hist2d(data3,data2, bins=(8,8))

for i in range(len(ybins)-1):
    for j in range(len(xbins)-1):
        ax.text(xbins[j]+0.3,ybins[i]+0.3, hist[i,j],color="w",ha="center", va="center", fontweight="bold")

plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, norm=mcolors.NoNorm)
```

I get below plot for this.
[image]

What I want to achieve is the color of each bin represent according to value inside it. Currently I see same color for bin with value 3 and 1 and zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just wrong to place the indexes.

**You should use:** `hist[j,i]`

**This is the bug:**  `hist[i,j]`

Therefore this code is correct:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.set_aspect("equal")
hist, xbins, ybins, im = ax.hist2d(data3,data2, bins=(8,8))

for i in range(len(ybins)-1):
    for j in range(len(xbins)-1):
        ax.text(xbins[j]+0.3,ybins[i]+0.3, hist[j,i],color="w",ha="center", va="center", fontweight="bold") #modificated

plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]